# Replicate / Backup Entire Site & SQL Databases To Remote Server With PHP Cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, cron, backup

I am trying to make a complete file & mySQL backup of my site each night.

I was thinking the best way of doing it would be to have a cronjob run each night that would login to a remote server and replicate all of the local files.

Then, I need to figure out a way to take backups of all the mysql databases (currently there are three) and upload them all to the remote server as well.

This sounds like a huge project and I don't know whether to reinvent the wheel here, or if there is some script out there which basically does the same thing already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cronjob to run a bash script

`mysqldump` the databases

`tar -cvf` the files

`wput` it all to your remote server

Also you can set a variable like `now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")` to use in your file names

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mysqldump` command to backup the database to a file and then upload to a different server
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

have you thought about MySQL replication? Maybe that fits better to your needs and you doesn't need php to do it
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html